# Maharam Discussing the Rosh

Tags: sources-mekorot, rabbis, rishonim, quotations, responsa

Is there a list of teshuvot (or other documents) in which the Maharam discusses his student the Rosh?

Comment: Have you tried using something like [this site](https://www.responsa.co.il/default.aspx?action=advancedSearch!yes) to search for e.g. the words אשר and יחיאל close to each other? That could give a good list, even if it might not be perfect.

Comment: @ba I assume you mean to search within the Maharam's teshuvot. Otherwise you will simply get a list of all sefarim that mention the Rosh.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that he ever discussed his student in his teshuvot other documents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Mechon Yerushalayim edition of Maharam's responsa includes an index of people mentioned. For R. Asher ben Yechiel, it includes the following:

[image]